# swift 3.0.2 gives ambitious error ''Type 'bool' is broken"

Tags: swift, swift3

i am using this struct and using this

```
struct Ride {
  var isRideForNow: Bool!    
}
 var sheduleRide: Ride?
 sheduleRide = Ride()
 sheduleRide?.isRideForNow = false
```

When i am using like this it works fine

```
 if (sheduleRide?.isRideForNow)! {
   //some code
 }
```

But i don't know why below code give the error "Type 'bool' is broken"  even there is no optional chaining inside this

```
 if (sheduleRide!.isRideForNow) {
   //some code
 }
```

Comment: schedule ride is optional i guess.so first option works not second.

Comment: ok , but why i sheduleRide! is explicitly unwrapped to break the optional thing.

Comment: Please compile on swift 3.1

Comment: done please look.

Comment: @SuryaKantSharma Thank you – however it still compiles fine for me in Swift 3.1 ([see for yourself](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/58f1d86bda4eb37edb42a231)). Interestingly enough however it doesn't compile in Swift versions 3.0 - 3.0.2. Are you sure you're running Swift 3.1?

Comment: sorry its swift 3.0.2 exactly. thanks for help.

Comment: @Hamish, Swift 2.2 gives a more sensible error. It thinks user is doing a `nil` test. Explicitly unwrapping the implicitly unwrapped optional solves the problem.  `if schedule!.isRideForNow! {`.

Comment: @vacawama Yup – in any case, OP's code is now working fine in Swift 3.1. It was [filed as a bug here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3552), and fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/6587). I guess one of us should should write an answer... :)

Comment: @Hamish, go ahead and write the answer.  You have the story well in hand.

Comment: Why is `isRideForNow` an optional at all?  Do you really need `false / maybe /  true`. The concept of Swift is to avoid optionals as much as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a useless error message – which appears only to be present in Swift versions 3.0 to 3.0.2. The problem is that Swift is not implicitly unwrapping the optional, as it thinks you're trying to do an optional check.

The solution therefore, [as @vacawama says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423315/swift-3-0-2-gives-ambitious-error-type-bool-is-broken#comment73908161_43423315), is to simply explicitly unwrap the optional:

```
if sheduleRide!.isRideForNow! {
    // some code
}
```

(which of course will crash if either `sheduleRide` or `isRideForNow` is `nil`)

However, the fact that Swift isn't implicitly unwrapping the IUO here, in my view, is not in line with the IUO behaviour detailed in [SE-0054](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md) – in that IUOs should be treated as strong optionals where they can be type-checked as them, but otherwise should be implicitly unwrapped.

In a boolean condition, the compiler cannot type-check the expression as a strong optional, therefore really it *should* be implicitly unwrapped. This behaviour was [filed as a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3552) and fixed [in this pull request](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/6587), so the statement:

```
if sheduleRide!.isRideForNow {
    // some code
}
```

now compiles fine in Swift 3.1.

But really, [as @vadian says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423315/swift-3-0-2-gives-ambitious-error-type-bool-is-broken#comment73908341_43423315), you should be thinking about whether `isRideForNow` should be an IUO. You should only make it one if it *needs* to have delayed initialisation (and can't otherwise
 be `lazy`).

If you're giving it a value upon initialisation, then it can be non-optional:

```
struct Ride {
    var isRideForNow: Bool
}

var sheduleRide = Ride(isRideForNow: false)
```

Comment: There is a lot going on here, including that fact that when dinosaurs roamed the earth it was possible to check if an optional was nil with `if myOptionalVar { // not nil }` but that caused confusion when the variable was `Bool?` and `Bool!`.

Comment: @vacawama Indeed, that was really a hangover from the (Obj-)C behaviour of testing for `nil`/`NULL`, and I'm glad it was removed. I think for the principle of least surprise, the current (Swift 3.1) behaviour for `Bool!`/`Bool?` expressions in an if-statement has it about right. Although really for a completely surprise-free experience, avoiding IUOs wherever possible is a good way to go :)

Comment: *hangover* is a much better word than *holdover* in this case :-). I wholeheartedly agree that avoiding IUOs wherever possible is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

using explicitlyVar! while using is the way-around which work for me